# decorator: understanding why it does not flush local variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I've written a simple decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
import random

def my_dec(f):
    lst = list()

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        lst.append(random.randint(0, 9))
        print(lst)
        return f(*args)

    return wrapper

@my_dec
def foo():
    print("foo called")
```

Now, if I call `foo` multiple times `lst` is not being flushed. Instead, it builds up over time. Thus, multiple calls of `foo` return an output like this:

```
foo()
> [4]
> foo called

foo()
> [4, 9]
> foo called

foo()
> [4, 9, 1]
> foo called

...
```

Why is that? I thought a `decorator` is just syntactic sugar for `my_dec(foo)`?! I assumed that each call to `my_dec` flushes `lst`.

Comment: You're right that the decorator is just syntactic sugar for `foo = my_dec(foo)` ... But I don't see how that would lead you to think that `lst` would be "flushed".  Be careful here -- `my_dec` is only getting called once, no matter how many times you call `foo`...

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I thought `my_dec` is called every time `foo` is called, but obviously it is not, since `foo = my_dec(foo)` only happens once. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Additional question: can I access `lst` somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right... The decorator is just syntactic sugar.  Specifically:

```
@decorator
def foo():
    pass
```

is *exactly* the same thing as:

```
def foo():
    pass
foo = decorator(foo)
```

Let's be a little more outlandish and rewrite this another way that is *mostly* equivalent<sup>1</sup>:

```
def bar():
    pass
foo = decorator(bar)
del bar
```

Hopefully written out this way, you can see that if I call `foo` a bunch of times, I'm *not* calling `decorator` a bunch of times.  `decorator` only got called once (to help create `foo`).

Now in your example, your decorator creates a list immediately when it gets called:

```
def my_dec(f):
    lst = list()  # list created here!

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        lst.append(random.randint(0, 9))
        print(lst)
        return f(*args)

    return wrapper
```

The function returned `wrapper` gets assigned to your `foo`, so when you call `foo`, you're calling `wrapper`.  Note that there is no code in `wrapper` that would reset `lst` -- only code that would add more elements to `lst` so there is nothing here to indicate the `lst` *should* get "flushed" between calls.

<sup><sup>1</sup>(depending on what the decorator does, you might see some differences in the function's `__name__` attribute, but otherwise it's the same thing...)</sup>

---

Also note that you'll have one `lst` for each time the decorator is called.  We can go crazy with this one if we like and decorate `foo` twice:

```
@my_dec
@my_dec
def foo():
    pass
```

Or we can decorate more than one function:

```
@my_dec
def foo():
    pass

@my_dec
def bar():
    pass
```

And then when we call `foo` and `bar`, we'll see that they each accumulate their own (distinct) lists of random numbers.  In other words, each time your decorator is applied to something, a new list will be created and each time that "something" is called, the list will grow.

Comment: Well put - nice explanation! Additional question: every decorated function `foo_n` gets its own `lst`, right? Thus, I could possibly memorize stuff this way? Is there some way to access `lst`?

Comment: @ascenator -- I was just updating my edit to say that each gets it's own `lst`.  There isn't a _clean_ way to access the list.  You _can_ add it as an attribute to the function (`wrapper`) before you return it... `wrapper.lst = lst; return wrapper`, but that starts feeling a little kludgy

Comment: You mean it's not *pythonic* to save & load values with decorators this way? Or that there generally is no clean way to store specific data (and read it later on) with decorators? It just came to my mind, because it sounds like a nice idea to me to store values this way. Otherwise one would have to do this by hand every time `foo_n` gets called.

Comment: @ascenator -- I mean that it's a little weird to monkey-patch attributes on functions (most people won't expect functions to have attributes).  Without knowing the exact requirements here, it's hard to give general advice... Some alternatives are to create a class and provide the decorator via an instance method of the class -- That way you can track the values on a class and not as a one-off attribute on the function.  _But_, that's not _particularly_ clear either... As I said, I think I'd need to know more about the specific problem before giving solution advice.

Comment: I do not have a specific use case, yet. I just thought, for example, one could possibly profile or at least count function calls. Or building an own cache lookup for functions that require lots of computation time, while their return values easily fit in memory. That way it would be even possible to have a look at all values calculated so far. Or implementing buffers, ... in short: I was just thinking about use cases where storing information and having access to it later on would be nice.

Comment: @ascenator Yes, you can use decorators for that. Have a look at [memoization decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) and [number of function calls decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Counting_function_calls). Whether or not you should depends on your use-case.

Comment: @ascenator -- For the caching, you could look at the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l391) of [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).  The api looks like they do monkey-patch the function with attributes/methods...  For call counting you should probably just use the `profile` module :-).