# I don't understand why this value changes on leetcode?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am working on improving my recursion skills via leetcode. I ran into this problem.

Implement pow(x,n)

Although I know the following isn't the best code. I don't understand why it works when I run it in local mode (on leetcode) and not when I submit. I read over the appropriate [link](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011834174-I-encountered-Wrong-Answer-Runtime-Error-for-a-specific-test-case-When-I-test-my-code-using-this-test-case-it-produced-the-correct-output-Why-) on leetcode which seems to imply the decorator may be reusing the cache multiple times? I know the various ways I can modify this too work, I just want to understand why the cache dictionary is behaving erroneously as it does.

```
class Solution:
    def myPow(self,x,n):        
        if n == 1:
            return(x)
        elif n == 0:
            return(1)
        else:
            if n < 0:
                x = 1/x
                n = -1*n
            return(recursion(x,n))
    
def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(arg0,arg1):
        if arg1 not in cache:
            cache[arg1] = float(func(arg0,arg1)) 
        return(cache[arg1])
    
    return(wrapper)

@memoize
def recursion(x,n):
    if n == 0:
        return(float(1.0000))
    else:
        val = float(recursion(x,n//2))
        if n%2 == 0:
            return float(val*val)
        else:
            return float(val*val*x)
```

================================ EDIT =============================
After exploring a bit more, it appears that the cache isn't being reset.

```
res = Solution().myPow(2,10)
print(res)
res = Solution().myPow(2.1,10)
print(res)
```

I get the results 1024 twice. So it appears that the cache isn't being reset. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: maybe is some rounding error by forcing it to be a float, for example `2**10000 == recursion(2,10000)` give false for this very reason

Comment: My only guess is that the wrapper method is staying in the global namespace. I can hack together a better solution, namely placing cache in mypow, initilizing it to {} then providing it to memoize. But is there a better way to do it in the decorator?

Comment: why you think that your cache decorator would be reset in each call? your recursive function is outside of your class so is created and decorated only once and stay with that decoration forever, so yes it reuse the cache

Comment: Thanks @Copperfield, what would be the appropriate way to modify this code, preferably decorator or when I call recrusive, so that cache gets reset everytime a new function wants to do the recursion?

Comment: and about doing it better, yes, I just notice that you use only the second argument as a key for you cache dictionary, so as you notice, whatever you do myPow(x,n) you will get the first result with that n, regardless of x... an easy solution for this is just use both as key: `cache[(arg0,arg1)]=func(arg0,arg1)`

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't grow the cache as quickly? This will cause the cache to become huge as we use more values.

Comment: you can check in your wrapper function the size of the cache and remove items from it if it is bigger that some value of your choosing, or as you mention, you can make it part of solution class somehow so when you make a new instance of it you get a fresh new cache and stuff

Comment: Thanks, I also found this as a result of our discussionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011744/decorator-understanding-why-it-does-not-flush-local-variables.